# runspace New-MsolLicenseOptions commandparameter

Tags: c#, powershell, office365, runspace

I am trying to write a console application to manage user license options in Office 365. I am using runspace in conjunction with the MSOL powershell module. Basically i am able to manage all the users licence requirements with exception of the -DisabledPlans when i pass a list of disabled plans in the commandparameter.

The following is the PowerShell command which works fine and disables all the plans as expected

```
New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId ACME:ENTERPRISEPACK -DisabledPlans OFFICESUBSCRIPTION,SHAREPOINTWAC,EXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE,SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE
```

I build this runspace commandparamater as follows

```
     Command licenseOptions = new Command("New-MsolLicenseOptions");
                licenseOptions.Parameters.Add((new CommandParameter("AccountSkuId", "ACME:ENTERPRISEPACK")));
                licenseOptions.Parameters.Add((new CommandParameter("DisabledPlans", 
"OFFICESUBSCRIPTION,SHAREPOINTWAC,EXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE,SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE,YAMMER_ENTERPRISE")));
```

When i build the commandparameter above in runspace and execute i receive the following {"Unable to assign this license because the license options are invalid."}

however when i use the following commandparameter it successfully disables the serviceplan

```
 Command licenseOptions = new Command("New-MsolLicenseOptions");
                licenseOptions.Parameters.Add((new CommandParameter("AccountSkuId", "ACME:ENTERPRISEPACK")));
                licenseOptions.Parameters.Add((new CommandParameter("DisabledPlans", "EXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE")));
```

I have been debugging and i can see that only one item exists in the disabled list object with a value of OFFICESUBSCRIPTION,SHAREPOINTWAC,EXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE,SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE,YAMMER_ENTERPRISE

where i would be expecting a item for each entry. I think it maybe how the runspace commandparameter is interpreting the separators.

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 1):

I passing in the array as string and i should have passed a List instead

```
            List<string> disabledplans = new List<string>();

            disabledplans.Add("OFFICESUBSCRIPTION");
            disabledplans.Add("SHAREPOINTWAC");
            disabledplans.Add("EXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE");
            disabledplans.Add("SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE");
            disabledplans.Add("YAMMER_ENTERPRISE");

            Command licenseOptions = new Command("New-MsolLicenseOptions");
            licenseOptions.Parameters.Add((new CommandParameter("AccountSkuId", "ACME:ENTERPRISEPACK")));
            licenseOptions.Parameters.Add((new CommandParameter("DisabledPlans", disabledplans)));
```